# Improve if containsKey in map by java 8 interface

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I've got entity/form called Time with fields:

```
Integer id;
Date date;
Integer value;
```

And another form called SummaryForm

```
String title;
String descr;
List<Object> newList;
```

How to improve map usage with Java 8 interface.
Right now I've got an if statement:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).newList().add(new SummaryForm(time.getDate(), time.getValue()));
        }
```

Is there any simple way to improve it to avoid if statements, t with map.containsKey?
In my opinion, I need something like putIfPresent, but it seems there is an only putIfAbsent method.

Comment: How about `computeIfPresent`?

Comment: I'm gonna check it in documentation, but can you print an answer with that as solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several new methods in Java 8 that extend among other things the `Map` interface, thanks to the introduction of default methods (so backwards compatibility is kept).

There's no `putIfPresent`, but there are `replace()` method(s) which would work that way.

However it looks like your looking for `computeIfPresent` here:

```
map.computeIfPresent(key, (k, value) -> {
    value.newList().add(new SummaryForm(time.getDate(), time.getValue());
    return value;
})
```

Comment: Since you were so quick I donated the first part of my answer here.

Comment: @Kayaman ))) I pressed `edit` and was like... WHAT? many more characters than I had put in

Comment: The alternative would be to have a dummy value object whose `newList()` method returns something that ignores all `add` requests. Then, you could write `map.getOrDefault(key, SINK).newList().add(new SummaryForm(time.getDate(), time.getValue());`…

Comment: Can I ask you guys if its a real improvement of my code? Because it looks "bigger" now.

Comment: @degath some people think bigger is better. Nobody would compare the two codes and say "oh yes, using `computeIfPresent` is definitely an improvement". But if you were working in a multi-threaded context and `map` were a `ConcurrentMap`, there would be an actual functional difference (the latter way being atomic).

Comment: @degath  you could simplify your initial code by not doing two searches via `containsKey` and `get`, but only do a single `get` and check if the return value is `null`

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. I think my head is just too small to get the knowledge you try to share with me. It seems I need to rest and sleep with it :)

Comment: @Holger oh my! it only took me 21 minutes to understand what you mean

Comment: @Eugene sadly, I can't see how quickly you answer it, :(.

Comment: hi, @Eugene. what does Holger mean? use a dummy object to skip re-putting?

Comment: @holi-java think about this way, what the OP initially wants is : if his map contains a certain key, that value should be updated somehow, otherwise NOOP (do nothing). what Holger is saying do a `getOrDefault(key, SOME_DUMMY_VALUE).newList().add(new SummaryForm(time.getDate(), time.getValue())`, where `newList().add(new SummaryForm(time.getDate(), time.getValue())` is the actual "update the value" I was referring to.

Comment: @holi-java now, if `SOME_DUMMY_VALUE` would have the method `newList().add(Date date, String value){ return; // basically NOOP }`, you would mimic what the OP wants to do. If the key is present, it performs the "update" of the actual key from the map, if the value is missing it performs the update of the "mock/stub/dummy" (call it how you want it), without any side-effect on the key from the map. this is somehow complicated to me, but Holger's mind works in other way than mine and yours probably :)

Comment: @Eugene you absolute right, since think of skip re-putting is trivial.